# Purpose of assigning var as void 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand the libraries used in [this article](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/how-to-write-a-google-maps-react-component/) and elsewhere, and there's some pretty mind bending stuff in there, among which is the line

```
var cb = void 0;
```

I've learned that `void 0` returns `undefined`, but isn't a `var` undefined by default? Why not just use the following instead?

```
var cb;
```

Comment: void 0 is actually shorter than undefined, hence it reduces the code length.

Comment: Note that I am not asking what void 0 does, but why it is made explicit in this case.

Comment: I am starting to think that this code might be the output of a code generator or transpiler, which would satisfy me as to why it may not be idiomatic Javascript.

Comment: yes, sorry, what I meant is that you usually find void 0 instead of undefined because, since it's shorter, transpilers takes advantages over that to reduce the length of the transpiled code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. JavaScript variables are automatically initialized to `undefined`. So given that `void 0` returns `undefined`, these two statements do exactly the same thing:

```
var cb;
```

or

```
var cb = void 0;
```

Well... Not *quite* the same thing. Here's a case where it would make a difference:

```
function foo() {
    var cb;
    // some stuff
    cb = 42;
    // a lot more stuff, lots of lines of code here!
    // ... really a lot of code here ...
    // ... so much code that I forgot the first part of the function...
    var cb;  // I forgot that I already defined cb above!
    alert( cb );  // Do I expect undefined? I will be surprised!
}
```

So one might use `var cb = void 0;` in the second part of that function just to make sure that `cb` wasn't accidentally assigned a value above. OTOH, many IDEs will give you a warning on that second `var` declaration, so you would be ignoring that warning at your own risk.

In any case, this kind of repeated variable declaration is often a sign of a badly written function, one that does too much and ought to be broken up into smaller functions.

A couple of other possible reasons I can think of for doing the `var cb = void 0;`:

1. To make it explicit that the variable is being set to `undefined` (assuming that the reader knows that `void 0` returns `undefined`!). But this isn't necessary, since it is well defined that JavaScript initializes variables to `undefined` automatically
2. Having cut their teeth on a language like C where a newly declared variable is initialized to random garbage, they don't trust that the right thing will happen if they leave out the assignment. This isn't necessary either, since JavaScript is not C.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe to make sure `cb` is initialised with `undefined` and nothing else (undefined was writable in ES3).